# MySQL JOIN pass PHP variable to two tables

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following MySQL query in PHP that passes a variable to complete the query:

```
SELECT * from mobile_tech WHERE uid=$uid  order by timestamp DESC limit 0,1
```

I have the following MySQL JOIN that provides data from two tables:

```
SELECT mobile_tech.latitude, mobile_tech.longitude, mobile_tech.timestamp, mobile_tech.uid, gbl_qemplisting.EmpNo, gbl_qemplisting.FirstName, gbl_qemplisting.LastName 
FROM mobile_tech, gbl_qemplisting
WHERE mobile_tech.uid=gbl_qemplisting.EmpNo AND date(timestamp)='$currentday' 
group by uid
```

I need to combine these two queries into one with a JOIN and still passing the $uid variable to complete the query.

I've tried the following and it did not work:

```
SELECT mobile_tech.latitude, mobile_tech.longitude, mobile_tech.timestamp, mobile_tech.uid, gbl_qemplisting.EmpNo, gbl_qemplisting.FirstName, gbl_qemplisting.LastName 
FROM mobile_tech, gbl_qemplisting
WHERE mobile_tech.uid=$uid AND gbl_qemplisting.EmpNo=$uid AND date(timestamp)='$currentday'
```

Comment: It would help if you post an example of input rows from the two tables and the output you want the query to produce. You have a `GROUP BY` but no aggregate functions (`COUNT(),SUM(),MAX()` etc) so it isn't clear what the intended result should be. Is there to be only one row returned? How many would be expected from the `gbl_qemplisting` table?

Comment: I want to output the values specified in the select from the two tables.  The original JOIN achieves this by comparing and matching to produce the values indicated.  I need to produce those same values but instead of matching I need to pass the PHP variable to achieve the same result.  Group By is not necessary.

Comment: What does "did not work" mean? What happens when you input the query directly into MySQL?

Comment: The original query produces one row per employee because of the `GROUP BY`. The last query will return the cross product between the two tables. If one table has 5 rows for the employee, and the other has 2 rows, you'll get 10 rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query will return a cross product between the `mobile_tech` and `gbl_emplisting` rows for `$uid`. If you just want one row, as in the first query, use `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT` similarly.

```
SELECT mobile_tech.latitude, mobile_tech.longitude, mobile_tech.timestamp, mobile_tech.uid, gbl_qemplisting.EmpNo, gbl_qemplisting.FirstName, gbl_qemplisting.LastName 
FROM mobile_tech, gbl_qemplisting
WHERE mobile_tech.uid=$uid AND gbl_qemplisting.EmpNo=$uid AND date(timestamp)='$currentday'
ORDER BY mobile_tech.timestamp
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Excellent, really appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1):

Please try with this and say the result

```
SELECT mobile_tech.latitude, 
mobile_tech.longitude, 
mobile_tech.timestamp,
mobile_tech.uid,
gbl_qemplisting.EmpNo,
gbl_qemplisting.FirstName,
gbl_qemplisting.LastName
FROM mobile_tech inner join gbl_qemplisting
        on mobile_tech.uid=gbl_qemplisting.EmpNo 
where mobile_tech.uid=$uid AND date(timestamp)='$currentday'
```